# how to make a bash alias to a script in folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, python

i have a pyton script that execute with `python script.py` when you are in the same folder.

I want to know if it's possible to make a bash alias like `alias script='command'` to execute the script also when you are outside the same folder than the script?

thx

Answer (score 0):

I find it by myself you just have to make an alias like this :

```
alias script="python /home/name/folder/script.py"
```

and that's all.